# Count variables per group at time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I am collecting data about a fleet of vehicles at 10 minute intervals. The following query returns 144 rows as expected (the number of 10-minute intervals in one day).

```
  select distinct(date_trunc('minute', (((time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'EST'))) FROM fleet_history WHERE (((time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'EST') BETWEEN '2017-11-30 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2017-11-30 23:59:59'::timestamp ORDER BY date_trunc DESC
```

In the table `fleet_history`, there is another column named `repair_state` - a character column that contains the description of whether the vehicle is "working" or "in repair" or "other".

```
select * FROM fleet_history limit 5

  id repair_state                time
1  1      working 2017-11-22 15:45:34
2  2    in repair 2017-11-22 15:45:34
3  3      working 2017-11-22 15:45:34
4  4      working 2017-11-22 15:45:34
5  5        other 2017-11-22 15:45:34
```

My objective is to, at each 10-minute interval, output the truncated time, and number (count) of working vehicles, in repair vehicles and other, (grouping by interval).

How would one write this query in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Left join a calendar table, whose records correspond to 10 minute intervals, to your `fleet_history` table.  Then aggregate by interval to get the counts.

Comment: If you can deal with taking the difference (in minutes) between `2017-11-30 00:00:00` (constant) and `time` column and call it `offset`, you can create a column `interval` = `offset` mod 10. Then, do a select count(*) grouping by `offset` and `repair_state`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach creates a CTE calendar table containing the ten minute intervals on a given day.  Then left join this calendar table to your `fleet_history` table on the condition that the time falls within a given ten minute interval.  Finally, do a conditional aggregation over each each interval and count the various types of repair states.

```
with calendar as (
    select i from generate_series('2017-11-22', 
    '2017-11-23', '10 minute'::interval) i
)

select
    t1.i,
    sum(case when t2.repair_state = 'working'   then 1 else 0 end) as working_cnt,
    sum(case when t2.repair_state = 'in repair' then 1 else 0 end) as repair_cnt,
    sum(case when t2.repair_state = 'other'     then 1 else 0 end) as other_cnt
from calendar t1
left join fleet_history t2
    on t2.time >= t1.i and t2.time < t1.i + INTERVAL '10 min'
group by
    t1.i
order by
    t1.i;
```

Follow the link below for a running demo.  It is a bit contrived, because your sample data included only 5 records, all from the same 10 minute interval.

### Demo